# Disable certain scripts for mobile devices

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

These days, most everything on a website can be responsive (size properly for different screen sizes). One last thing I haven't found a solution for is jQuery plugins. For example, I'm using a plugin that animates some floating particles in the background of the site. It looks great on desktop, but stutters on a smartphone.

I would like to hear thoughts & ideas about how you could disable a script if the page is loaded in a mobile sized browser. Utilizing javascript to do this would be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MatchMedia.js https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js and only load the plugins if above a certain viewport size.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good way to detect if the browser is a mobile : http://www.jquery4u.com/mobile/detect-mobile-devices-jquery/

Use [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to load your scripts according to the browser.